# How to include untracked files in a command like `git commit --dry-run -a`

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, git-add

I'd like to review that Git is going to properly detect files as moved, rather than deleted/added new - but there doesn't seem to be any way to preview the operation - it seems like my only option is `git add . --dry-run`, which then I can't see the resulting status of. Is there any other option?

I expected `git commit --dry-run .` would work, but it still excludes the untracked files.

Comment: `-a` in `git commit` does not affect untracked files.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to review that Git is going to properly detect files as moved, rather than deleted/added new ...

This kind of detection happens *long after you've committed*, and is optional, on a per-"maybe-detect-maybe-don't" basis.  That is:

```
git diff --no-renames <old> <new>
```

or:

```
git diff --find-renames[=<threshold>] <old> <new>
```

presents *two different views* of the difference between some old and new commit.

Neither view is "more accurate".  Imagine you're looking at a big building, like the Empire State Building in NY or the Shard in London or the Burj Khalifa in Dubai.  Which view is more accurate: one from a drone, one from the street, or one looking at parts of the interior?  The view you see, depending on which of these you select, is different; but the building hasn't changed.  The same is true of Git's commit snapshots: once made, a commit's snapshot *cannot* be changed.  It is frozen for all time.  It is the way it is, and nothing can change that.  Comparing that snapshot to another snapshot just gives you one particular *view* of that snapshot ("you already know what the old one was, so here's how I describe how the new one differs").

Consider using `git add` and then `git status`: the `git status` command defaults to doing move-detection with the threshold level set to 50%, which is also the default for `git diff` in modern Git (since Git version 2.9).